# DeviantArt's script responsible for sending profile comments

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I'm trying to write an greasemonkey script for DeviantArt.com that will send comment if i visit specified profile. I've already written script that can type in the text I want to send, but I've got a problem with sending it.

My code for clicking "Submit comment" button which should work is:
`$(".smbutton.smbutton-green.smbutton-big.comment-submit").first().click()`
The selector is good, it perfectly selects the "Submit comment" button element, but the script  just doesn't click it.
What's the most curious is that - if I paste this line to browser's console it works perfectly!

Those one's doesn't work too:
`$(".smbutton.smbutton-green.smbutton-big.comment-submit")[0].click()`
`$(".smbutton.smbutton-green.smbutton-big.comment-submit")[0].trigger('click')`

The full script where this line is included:
`

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       DaHubAutoClicker
// @version    1.0
// @description  
// @require    http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js
// @match      http://dahub.deviantart.com/
// @match      http://*.deviantart.com/*
// ==/UserScript==
console.log("### DaHubAutoClicker started ###")
function sendd(){
     console.log("sending")
     $(".smbutton.smbutton-green.smbutton-big.comment-submit").first().click()
}
/* ############################################################ DaHub */
if(document.domain == "dahub.deviantart.com"){
    console.log("### DaHub")
    $("#commentbody").click(); /*IMPORTANT: the submit button appears after clicking that element*/
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.writer.no-lub.put-art-here.ui-droppable').text('newest');
        setTimeout(function(){sendd()},3500)
    },1500)
}  
/* ############################################################ Inne */
else{
    console.log("### Outside DaHub")
}
```

`

All the rest of code is perfectly working tho.

What's wrong with my code?
Or what is the other way to submit/send the comment?

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure you can't simulate clicks. Using `click()` would only call the `click` event handler for that element, which may not be registered. If the button in question is responsible for submitting a form it might be worth trying to submit the form directly, as follows:

```
document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
```

If on the other hand the submit function works with AJAX (i.e. via javascript) it would be worth reviewing the source code and look for the exact function that processes the comment, then you can call that function directly.

Comment: But this [...].click() code works when I paste it to browser's console.

Comment: @ThePatrollPL: for submitting the form you mean? If it works in the console it should work in your code too... what is the difference?

Comment: I am simulating click for this 'a' element: <a href="#" class="smbutton smbutton-green smbutton-big comment-submit" tabindex="2" onclick="GMI.up(this).sendClick();return GMI.evCancel()"><span class="post">Submit Comment</span></a>  Simulating the click works only when i do it through console, dunno why.

Comment: @ThePatrollPL: That HTML contains inline javascript for the `onclick` event, try using that javascript directly in your code. It's a bit strange, and you will likely need to substitute `this` for the element itself... it's really hard to provide a specific answer to this question without see full source code and how your script is running

Comment: Yes, I know it's a bit complicated. I will try to figure something. I tried also replacing 'this' with selector of this element but it throws errors from those onclick's functions. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: @ThePatrollPL: You will need to replace `this` with the element, for example: `$(".smbutton.smbutton-green.smbutton-big.comment-submit")[0]`

Comment: Oh, god... I know what's wrong... The DeviantArt's script can't see if there's something wrote while the textarea is still active after changes(propably onChange works that way) and empty message just can't be send.. Code worked in console because when clicking for console the textarea get deactivated, and  when I just let the script do it the textarea was still active because of no mouse used... That's just so annoying fact because it took me a couple of hours to realize this...

Comment: I would recommend either removing your question, or adding your own answer that explains exactly what the problem is and how you fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

The DeviantArt's script can't see if there's something wrote while the textarea is still active after changes and empty message just can't be send.

Code worked in console because when clicking for console the textarea lost focus, and when I just let the script do it the textarea was still focused because of no mouse used.

Using `$(':focus').blur()` before calling send button fixed the problem.